# Unable to return in if block while calculating GCD

Tags: python, greatest-common-divisor

I am trying to calculate a GCD of 2 numbers, the following code block works fine, I am using recursion, but when I am trying to return a value I am not able to do so, `return a` results in `None`

```
def gcd(a,b):
    if b == 0:
        print a
        return a   # This is not working 
    else:
        gcd(b,a%b)

XX = gcd(3, 5)
print (XX)
```

Output:

```
1
None
```

Comment: A function returns `None` is no explicit `return` statement is executed.

Comment: your recursive call to `gcd` needs to be returned, Like `return gcd(b,a%b)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code

```
def gcd(a,b):
    if b == 0:
        print a
        return a   # This is not working 
    else:
        gcd(b,a%b)

XX=gcd(3,5)
print (XX)
```

will not work, because you are missing the return statement in the line `gcd(b,a%b)`. So it should be

```
def gcd(a,b):
    if b == 0:
        print a
        return a
    else:
        return gcd(b,a%b)

print(gcd(12, 4))
```

By the way - if possible, don't code things yourself, use the predefined library:

```
from fractions import gcd
print(gcd(4, 12))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your recursion will not work... you are missing a `return` statement and also the algorithm does not work...

This is what a recursive gcd could look like:

```
def gcd(a,b):
    r = a % b
    if r == 0:
        return a
    elif r == 1:
        return 1
    return gcd(b, r)
```

and here a non-recursive gcd:

```
def gcd(a, b):
   while b:
       a, b = b, a % b
   return a
```

also note that you could just use [`math.gcd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html?highlight=gcd#math.gcd).